# Printing under Windows CE 6.0

Tags: printing, windows-ce

I am developing a device on ARM platform with Windows CE 6.0. One of the goals is to provide the user a possibility to print directly from the device (and not only text!). It means, that Windows will have to handle various types of printers. How can I realize such a functionality?

My guesses are:
- PCL printing (can you still get a PCL printer?)
- Network printing (how to do it - any example?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Printing is possible under Windows CE 6.0. There is an example of PCL driver in "\WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\DRIVERS\PRINTER\PCL". To include it in the OS Design set SYSGEN_PRINTING, SYSGEN_PCL and SYSGEN_USB_PRINTER to 1 in Configuraiton Properties --> Environment. It will result in compiling the sample and adding pcl.dll to OS Design. USB Printer Class driver will be also added.

Above action let us print text in ASCII code:

```
    // initialize printing
    //hPrinter = CreateFile(L"LPT1:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    //if (hPrinter == NULL) RETAILMSG(TRUE, (L"Error in OnClick5 (GUI): CreateFile() returned NULL"));

    // print text WORKS
    //WriteFile(hPrinter, szText, sizeof(szText), &cBytes, NULL);

    // close printer port
    //CloseHandle(hPrinter);
```

But to print for example BMP files, we need to really use the PCL driver (look at the following code). The problem is, that I cannot get rid of a bug: StartDoc() always returns "The network request is not supported". What is the proper way to start the print job?

```
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;
    HDC hdc = NULL;
    DOCINFO di;
    DEVMODE dm;

    // initialize DEVMODE struct
    memset(&dm, 0, sizeof(DEVMODE));
    wcscpy(dm.dmDeviceName, L"Hewlett-Packard LaserJet P3010 Series");
    dm.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    dm.dmPaperSize = DMPAPER_A4;
    dm.dmPrintQuality = DMRES_DRAFT;
    dm.dmFields = DM_PAPERSIZE | DM_PRINTQUALITY;

    //PAGESETUPDLG psd;
    //memset(&psd, 0, sizeof(psd));
    //psd.hwndOwner = NULL;
    //psd.hDevMode = NULL; 
    //psd.hDevNames = NULL;
    //psd.Flags = PSD_RETURNDEFAULT;
    //psd.lStructSize = sizeof(psd);

    //PageSetupDlg(&psd);
    //RETAILMSG(TRUE, (L"GUI: PageSetupDlg() result 0x%x", CommDlgExtendedError()));

    //if (psd.hDevMode == NULL) return -1;

    //DEVMODE* lpdm = (DEVMODE*)psd.hDevMode;

    DEVMODE* lpdm = &dm;

    // initialize device context
    hdc = CreateDC(L"pcl.dll", L"Printer", L"LPT1:", lpdm);
    if (hdc == NULL) {
        RETAILMSG(TRUE, (L"GUI: CreateDC() error 0x%x", GetLastError()));
        return -1;
    }

    // register abort procedure
    SetAbortProc(hdc, AbortProc);

    // initialize DOCINFO struct
    memset(&di, 0, sizeof(DOCINFO));
    di.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
    di.lpszDocName = L"logo.bmp";
    di.lpszOutput = NULL;
    di.lpszDatatype = 0;
    di.fwType = 0;

    // print file
    if (StartDoc(hdc, &di) <= 0) {
        RETAILMSG(TRUE, (L"Error in OnClick5 (GUI): StartDoc() returned non-positive value"));
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), 0, (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);
        RETAILMSG(TRUE, ((LPWSTR)lpMsgBuf));
        LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
        DeleteDC(hdc);
        return -1;
    }
```